# how to calculate new transform of nodes when some of them are hidden

Tags: d3.js

I would like to calculate new position of nodes when some of them are hidden with css `display: "none";`

Here is jsFiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/krancan/xqeh5cba/3/ In line 44 i am trying to calculate new transform, but d3 also take into account hidden nodes. How do I ignore hidden nodes?

Hidden node must be displaying again when I zooming into cluster.

Comment: You need to remove the data for those hidden nodes before passing it to the pack layout.

Comment: I select nodes with
    var nodes = pack.nodes(root);
    nodes = nodes.filter(function(d){return d.depth <= 2});
but then nothing rendering.

Comment: You need to filter them *before* passing them to the pack layout. That is, you need to filter what's in `root`.

Comment: OK, but this filter() function on root (root is json file) not work. Is there any other function in d3 to filter json by depth?

Comment: This is before D3 gets involved, so you can use the Javascript `.filter()` function.

Comment: I have no idea how... root = root.filter(function(d){ return d.depth < 3 }); not work.